# Is there possibility to create *.config file from scratch programatically in .NET (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

For our approach we want to create one of the *.config files from scratch and populate it with some default/custom values at runtime.

Is there possibility to do this programatically via ConfigurationManager or something like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. As you point out, the `ConfigurationManager` class allows you to read and write config files.

[`ConfigurationManager` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)

Scroll down a bit.

Sure, you can read / write these files as XML files, but the above class exposes a much handier interface for manipulating config files.

To trick the `ConfigurationManager` into opening an arbitrarily named config file, you can [ab?]use`ExeConfigurationFileMap`. Note that `file` may not exist, in which case it will be created when you call `Save()`

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap
{
    ExeConfigFilename = file
};
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
//todo manipulate config. add settings / connection strings etc.
config.Save();
```

Comment: I didn't know this. An example of why I browse stackoverflow on a daily basis.

Comment: Actually, as I see it doesn't allow me save file initially. It allows me open existing config and make changes to it, then save. So looks like idea with creating file with File/XML Writer is good.

Comment: Ok, ConfigurationManager is indeed good for manipulating existing config file, but we will have to create it with XMLTextWriter, as is mentioned in other answer.

Comment: @Kyle Rozendo, you *can* create a config with `ConfigurationManager` I edited this answer to show how it's done

Comment: For me, it would create the file only with this code instead of config.Save():
        if (!fileExists) {
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal, true);
        }

Answer (score 3):

Since .config files are just XML, you should be able to just use an `XmlTextWriter` to build your config file.

Comment: Yeah... this makes sense. Will see if people have more smooth approaches and if not will accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Andriy - This answer should be used to create the initial file for sure, then use the `ConfigurationManager` class thereafter - however, why not just use it as it is defined right now? Is there any purpose?

Comment: Actually, other developers within my project asked me about this, so I'm not sure why they need such cumbersome approach. Maybe, I have to find this out.

Comment: @Kyle Rozendo, you *can* create a config with `ConfigurationManager` I edited the accepted answer to show how it's done

Answer (score 0):

sure it is, it's a simple and plain xml file

now... what `config` file are you writing about? `app.config`? `web.config`? `custom.config`?

first two are **configuration support for the windows app and web app**, so you would need to generate  from an "**outside**" app and then fire that app up (witch that already happens with the Setup project where it asks for the user things and you can edit/add to the configuration file, like Database connections, etc)

Comment: It should be app.config. I don't want to use any "outside" app.

Comment: you can have a Setup window and write to it, it is not protected, then ask to restart (or restart the app automatically) so it can reload all new stuff. Though I would use the Setup if it's only one time change, has you did not mention what do you want to add/change. :)